# How do I insert the text of the Split function into different lines inside a table in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need help with some code. I built a User Form in word using Bookmarks as references to where the text in each TextBox should go, I was able to accomplish that.  The challenge I'm having now is using the Split Function.  I want to grab each word from TextBox3 and place them in a table, then I want to search each word in an excel database and retrieve the info on the cell next to it (in a Vlookup sort of way). Each word from the TextBox3 should be in a different line.

Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With ActiveDocument
.Bookmarks("bmCN").Range _
.InsertBefore TextBox1
.Bookmarks("bmOriJob").Range _
.InsertBefore TextBox2
.Bookmarks("bmOptJob").Range _
.InsertBefore TextBox3
.Bookmarks("bmJobD").Range _
.InsertBefore TextBox4
.Bookmarks("bmJobRes").Range _
.InsertBefore TextBox5
.Bookmarks("bmJobR").Range _
.InsertBefore TextBox6
.Bookmarks("bmBen").Range _
.InsertBefore TextBox7
.Bookmarks("bmTag").Range _
.InsertBefore TextBox8

End With
 UserForm1.Hide
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Fields.Update
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this with array and loop:

*(see some comments inside the code below)*

```
'let's create temporary array
Dim tmpArray As Variant
    tmpArray = Split(TextBox3, " ")


Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To UBound(tmpArray)

    'we will load values to first column in first table in yur document
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range = tmpArray(i - 1)

    'here do your stuff with excel- load what you need
    'ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(i, 2).Range = something from excel
Next i
```

Comment: Tried it and for some reason it only gets the second word I tested it using "Automotive Parking Specialist" and only the Word Parking was transfered, also noticed the code does not specify the Header of the table so the array should go to the first column second row. A little bit of topic does the function `=Proper()` work so I can have each line starting with Capital letters or should have something like `Selection.Range.Case = wdUpperCase` With the selection being the first letter of each line?

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at it?

Comment: you could use `StrConv(tmpArray(i - 1),vbProperCase)` to get `Proper text`. Try to adjust code to your need where `Cells(row, column)` are the syntax referring to appropriate cell in the table.